# Why does multiplying an image, loaded using scikit-image, by 0.5 show it brighter in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-image, brightness

I simply want to darken an image that I've loaded using scikit-image in python.

If I do this:

```
test_image = io.imread("TestProvs2.bmp")

test_image = test_image * 0.5

show_map(test_image)
```

The array of RGB values does indeed get scaled down, so that each RGB value is 127.5.

Yet the resulting image has maximum values (left = original, right = new):
[image]

Comment: What's the data type of the array, and how are you displaying the image?

Comment: what is `show_map`?

Comment: please amend your question to explain how you display your data. someone removed the matplotlib tag even though you use matplotlib and that's the source of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read an image, the data type of your image is `uint8`. When you multiply it by `0.5`, Python casts it to `float64` but an image must be `uint8`, so it gives this error

```
Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0.0, 127.5]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.
```

What you have to do is to cast it to `uint8` manually.

```py
test_image = (test_image * 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
```

Don't forget to import `numpy`

```py
import numpy as np
```

Generally, it's better to use OpenCV for image processing.

Comment: That did it, tysm!

Comment: OpenCV is not all that great for image processing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is indeed data types, and how ***matplotlib*** handles them.

When you have data of type `uint8`, the value range is expected to be from 0 to 255. An image **needs not be** uint8. It can have other data types too.

When you have data of type float/float64, the value range is *probably* expected to be 0.0 .. 1.0. ***Matplotlib*** expects this.

If you see a warning like this, that would be an indication of the issue:

`Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).`

Since you merely multiplied your values by 0.5, your value range is 0.0 .. 127.5

Taking that, while expecting a range of upto 1.0, blows out all the pixels.

You fix that either by scaling appropriately, or converting to `uint8` explicitly.

***matplotlib*** is perfectly fine to use, for displaying purposes. You just have to check the documentation for what any API will do with your data.

Comment: While matplotlib supports non `uint8`  dtypes, skimage gives a warning and doesn't save the image correctly,. Moreover, OpenCV throws an error.

Comment: the question does not involve trying to save the image. OP hasn't clarified the nature of `show_map` at all. I had to deduce the use of matplotlib from the screenshots. -- opencv is also not used in OP's question. it can't throw an error. if you see an error, please point it out, including your [mre]